# If statement never setting the value of a variable

Tags: vb.net

I have tried the following block of code without the page request in Linqpad which hits both the if and else statements, however, when running in the back end `collapseSummaryImagePath` is always empty.  How can this be?

```
Dim collapseSummaryImagePath As String = Page.Request.QueryString.Item("CollapseImagePath")
    If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(collapseSummaryImagePath) OrElse collapseSummaryImagePath Is Nothing Then
         collapseSummaryImagePath = "meep"
    Else
         collapseSummaryImagePath = "feep"
    End If
```

Given that `collapseSummaryImagePath` is set before the if/else why is it never being set to meep or feep?  Is there something within the grabbing of the query string value that may or not be there messing up the variable?

Currently I am testing when this value is missing from the query string because when I include it in the query string it works.  This only seems to break when the value is missing.

EDIT:
Seems I am just having trouble working with query strings in vb.net.  The following block logs the before and after logs of the for each but logs nothing within the for each.  I think I may need to just brush up on my syntax.

```
 DebugMsg("Begin for each")
 For Each key In Page.Request.QueryString.Keys
     DebugMsg("Query string: " + key)
 Next key
 DebugMsg("End for each")
```

Comment: are you sure the code get executed? can you tell us where it is?

Comment: is that block located in a sub of some sort?  the `Nothing` test is redundant

Comment: if it only work when CollapseImagePath is present, i will assume you have try with an empty catch

Comment: The code definitely executes as the lines above it run correctly.  It is in a child controls definition.  Going to add in some logging as I cannot debug the code directly. No empty catch.

Comment: Added a bit of logging and it seems like I cannot loop through the query string values, going to look into this.